# How to represent a Zoo in Object Oriented?

Tags: java, oop

i got this interview question about how to represent a Zoo in OOP
and my answer was that the Zoo will have property set animals, where **Animal** is an abstract class and all the animals in the zoo will extend it, it will contain the **species,city** properties.
and Zoo will extend the abstract class **Agricultural_land**, which contains the **space,place** properties.

and i got a question about if i have different types of birds, how to represent them in OOP and i said i will make another class for birds and different types of birds will extend it.

please give me your ideas.

Answer (score 6):

Main reason for asking open questions during an interview is a need for information on your skills. So, there is no `one good way` to answer such kind of question. Instead, you can consider which skills would like to demonstrate.

A few hints bellow:

- basic object analysis (how you create classes, methods or attributes)
- building of classes hierarchy (where inheritance is needed - when not)
- using interfaces
- Inversion of control
- design patterns (eg. does observer pattern is suitable for vets and animals health control?)
- your approach for building unit tests

Answer (score 5):

Any object is a combination of state (field values) and behaviour (methods logic). I think if you have to represent something as an object you better specify the context first. If you develop some land trading application then your Zoo should have fields like **cost**, **owner**, **lastSoldDate** and methods like **sell**, **changeOwner**, **calculateTax**. If you work on game then your Zoo will have **animals**, **trees** and so on. Clear context allows you to decide what is important for your object and what's not.

As for birds I suggest you to read first chapter of [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) book. There is very fun and clear explanation of how to design ducks hierarchy and how to avoid common pitfalls. They explain the *composition* over *inheritance* principal which become kind of enlightenment for me. Now I'm trying to avoid inheritance and design my objects as a set of components responsible for behaviour. And now no over 9000 classes for different birds, no complex classes hierarchy where you scratch your head if you need to add a new bird. That's really nice book :)

Answer (score 1):

Etymologically, the word "animal" derives from the Latin meaning a "living being, a being which breathes".Birds breathe and are members of the Animal Kingdom.

So **Bird** class will extend **Animal** class

Answer (score 0):

you could start way more higher in the extension tree....
you have a class "livingt hings" that gets extended by birds, which gets extended...

and a Zoo has more then only animals. It has roads, workers, visiters, trees, garbage cans...